# ¿Cómo se distingue entre “lo mismo” e “igual”?

Tags: gramática, vocabulario, adverbios

Durante mi tiempo de traducción al español, encontré unas palabras que me confunden, así:

“Se ven iguales”

“Hablan lo mismo”

¿Por qué no es “se ven los mismos” o “hablan iguales”?

Comment: Edité el título de tu pregunta. El verbo que significa "diferenciar" es "distinguir".

Comment: Gracias, mi culpa 

Answer (score 2):

"Se ven iguales" es comparativo al ingles "They look identical".  "Se ven los mismos" se refiere a que ambos no han cambiado, aunque entre ellos sean totalmente diferentes.  "Hablan lo mismo" se refiere a que hablan el mismo idioma.  "Hablan iguales" se refiere a que usan el mismo vocabulario y modismos.

Comment: Gracias por tu repuesta, es muy útil

Answer (score 0):

Varias cosas aquí.

*Se ven iguales* significa "al verlos parecen iguales". Es decir: a la vista, dos o más cosas o personas tienen el mismo aspecto. Usamos el adjetivo *iguales* en plural porque el sujeto es plural. Es una forma especial de usar un adjetivo, que sólo se aplica a ciertos verbos de percepción como *ver, escuchar, oír, sentir, oler*. De la misma forma se puede decir *Se oyen iguales* (también *Suenan iguales*), *Se ven diferentes*, etc.

*Hablan lo mismo* es algo extraña. *Lo mismo* significa "la misma cosa", pero en este caso es como un adverbio y significa "de la misma manera". Sin embargo no suena del todo bien. En algunos países de habla hispana, en una conversación informal, puede aparecer esta frase, pero lo más correcto sería decir *Hablan de la misma forma/manera*.  También se puede decir *Hablan igual*, donde *igual*, a pesar de ser un adjetivo, funciona como adverbio (*igualmente*). Hay unos cuantos adjetivos que pueden funcionar así: se puede decir por ejemplo *Hablan rápido*, *Hablan lento*, *Hablan bajo*, etc. El verbo *hablar* no es como los verbos de percepción que mencioné antes, y no se usa con adjetivos de la misma manera.

Si dijeras *Hablan los mismos*, se entendería que "Hablan las mismas personas".

Comment: Muchas gracias por toda de tu ayuda, son muy útiles